# Ошибка EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 wakeup

Tags: node.js

Ошибка типа:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 wakeup listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

Вопрос стоит ли обращать на нее внимание и увеличивать лимиты? Или можно игнорировать? По сути она никак не влияет

```
NodeJS 0.12.18
```

Comment: Обратить внимание стоит. Скорее всего проблемы в архитектуре вашего приложения. Попробуйте увеличить лимиты. Если сообщение сохранится, то да, утечка памяти.

Comment: И да, ваша версия сейчас не поддерживается и не получает обновления безопасности.